# Youtube videos suddenly all report "Invalid parameters" and won't play

Tags: youtube, flash

Running 11.10, with up-to-date Flash (11.1.102.55, which the Flash site agrees is the up-to-date version).  Every Youtube video reports a blank screen with the words, "Invalid parameters":

[image: http://gutfullofbeer.net/youtube.png]

I've tried fiddling with the player "hardware acceleration" setting, and that has no effect. Similarly, I've clicked and un-clicked and re-clicked the "storage" options in the global settings thing, also to no effect.

I haven't seen this in any google searches (though there are other problems described involved the "Invalid parameters" message) which makes me think it's a recent phenomenon.

*edit* — hmm, fails in Firefox but works in Chrome ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you already did but, have you tried "flash-aid" add-on for Firefox? It installs the best option for you. It has solved me problems several times after trying for hours by myself with no luck.

Comment: No I haven't tried that but I will now.  Thanks!

Comment: Worked.  It's odd that the plugin seemed to work OK in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't technically solve your problem, but I heartily recommend trying HTML5 videos on YouTube and sidestepping this whole nasty Flash business.

You can opt in at http://www.youtube.com/html5 then most/nearly all videos will work without touching flash at all.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo killall plugin-container
```

> and reload the page

This solution worked for me. Had incessantly been getting this particular error with videos that involved flash(html5 didn't seem to be available for them)

Comment: Yes, thanks for adding this - nuking the Flash container is certainly an important trick to know :-)